# Example of a bijective non-closed linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am looking for a counter example to the claim

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{D} \subseteq H$. Then the spectrum of an unbounded linear operator $A: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow H$  decomposes into point-, continuous-, and residue-spectrum.

This is true when the operator $A$ is closed, since then $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}: A - z$ is also closed and thus is boundedly invertible if and only if it is bijective. So in particular I am looking for a non-closed linear operator $A: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow H$ s.t. $A - z$ is bijective for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

There may very well be an immediate example that I am missing, since I cannot come up with many non-closed operators to begin with.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depending on how non-constructive an "example" is allowed to be, let $e_r$ be some algebraic basis of $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ where $r$ runs over the reals $≥1$. Let $A: \ell^2\to \ell^2$ be defined by $A(\sum_r a_r e_r) = \sum_r r a_r e_r$. This is unbounded with domain and codomain Banach so its not closed. Further it is a linear bijection.